# FullCalendar click event not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a fullCalendar in which I dynamically add a remove icon on the events.
You can watch the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/archemedia/zpwmr7b0/).

In the fiddle you can see that on the top of the page, there is a remove icon which was added dynamically. Clicking on it will trigger a message in the console.
However, when I add the same code to the fullCalendar events (in the `eventRender` function), the same handler is added but is not triggered when you click on the icon.

Any idea why this won't work?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is a click event on dynamically created elements. If you change the click function to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".fc-event-delete-button", function(event) {
console.log("click", event);
})
```

That will fix the problem.

With dynamically created elements you need to write a click function like that. Attaching it to something already present on the page and specifying the exact element within the brackets.

Here's an updated [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpwmr7b0/2/) example

Comment: thanks Simon. In the fiddle it works but in my application it doesn't :(
Maybe I'm overlooking something still.
What puzzles me, is that in my original fiddle, the div I added on top of the page is also created dynamically and that one worked with my code. Could it be that there is an issue with fullCalendar itself?

Comment: @DanyDhondt I can't be certain what the issue is, but have you tried clearing the cache and testing the page again (that's been an issue for me on a few occasions). In your original fiddle that element is being created before the click function is being defined, so that might be why that one is working and the others aren't. To me, it doesn't look like an issue with fullCalendar.